# Universality : Working with one qubit

Tags: quantum-gate, pennylane

I am working on the Pennylane's code camp problems and I'm stuck with the [challenge 4](https://codecamp.xanadu.ai/dashboard/challenge/cfed2d79-7cd9-43ab-ba63-521805659f4f).
I am utterly clueless about this question, as in what is it asking from me, they provide us with a $2\times 2$ matrix that we have to approximate using variational methods,

We have to make the func `get_matrix`. I don't know which matrix do they want, DO they want us to first decompose that unitary in set of Rotation gates and then return a matrix `qml.matrix` and then find the cosine measure between both the matrix to check for similarity, I am totally lost here. I have contacted the help team, but haven't heard a reply, I just want to understand what they are asking here.

Comment: The problem is behind a paywall.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.